# Hot to get the cursor position in px in a contentEditable Div in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I need something like facebook when you write an @ in a contentEditable Div and then appears another div in the position of the cursor with a list of users, I have a modal with the div and I detetc the @ too, that is solve but I need to move the users list to the right.

I try this:

```
const range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
const rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
let cursorPos = rect.left
```

but I think this capture the distance with the screen not with the div, I need the distance in px and put this distance in the users list with `[style.left.px]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an event listener to check the mouse movement....

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event

```
yourHTMLElement = document.getElementById("element-id");

yourHTMLElement.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
   var xPos= event.clientX;
   var yPos= event.clientY;
   console.log(xPos, yPos);
});
```

In case you want to get the coordinates of the window object, change yourHTMLElement with window.